# Disambigtuation of the two popular "foreman" projects

Tags: foreman, theforeman

I beleive there are two very frameworks being used for deployments at the moment, both of which are called "foreman".  In the heroku world, foreman seems to reference  a software solution - i.e. we use it to run apps locally.  In the hardware world , I've seen references to a tool called "theforeman", which ironically, does something similar albeit for running bare metal machines.

Is there a public disambiguation between them, or any relation between them?

http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.3/quickstart_guide.html

and

http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/

Comment: I vote to leave this question open. This is a question about software tools (frameworks) commonly used by programmers, and the asker is asking an objective question (_i.e._ a question with an objective answer—"What's the difference, if any?"). SuperUser, for sure at least, isn't the place for this question.

Comment: I'm also going to vote to reopen: this is an objective, answerable question about programming tools.  Could you head over to Meta and ask for consensus on tag naming?  It's already a minefield and we *probably* want to *completely* disambiguate the SO tag naming here before jumping in head first...

Comment: At least one of these two is a tool _not_ intended for programmers, and even the briefest look at their respective websites is sufficient to disambiguate them.

Comment: Im not sure that disambiguating them is that easy.  After all, its not clear if the foreman github repo is unrelated to "theforeman" website or not, and its quite rare that any two software projects have the same name given the quirky nature of software naming.

Answer (score 0):

These are indeed two separate projects.

[The Foreman](http://theforeman.org/) is a management tool for physical and virtual servers. It helps system administrators manage servers throughout their lifecycle, from provisioning and configuration to orchestration and monitoring. It was created in 2009 and its github repositories lie here: https://github.com/theforeman

[Foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) is a manager for Procfile-based applications. Its aim is to abstract away the details of the Procfile format, and allow you to either run your application directly or export it to some other process management format. It was created in 2010 and its github repository lies here: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

The two projects are not related in any way and only happen to share the same name and programming language (both are written in ruby).